# audiograph c# UWP

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app, audio-recording

I'm trying to create a callrecorder for winphone at the UWP. I'm trying to do this with Audio graphs. I need to make a node for an input device (microphone), a node for an output device (speaker) and submit them to the file(wave/mp3).

I'm receiving an exception.

```
        AudioGraph graph;
        AudioDeviceInputNode deviceInputNode;
        AudioDeviceOutputNode deviceOutputNode;
        AudioFileOutputNode fileOutputNode;

        private async Task InitAudiographAsync()
        {

            AudioGraphSettings settings = new AudioGraphSettings(AudioRenderCategory.Speech);
            CreateAudioGraphResult result = await AudioGraph.CreateAsync(settings);
            if (result.Status == AudioGraphCreationStatus.Success)
            {
                graph = result.Graph;

                CreateAudioDeviceOutputNodeResult deviceOutputNodeResult = await graph.CreateDeviceOutputNodeAsync();

                if (deviceOutputNodeResult.Status == AudioDeviceNodeCreationStatus.Success)
                {
                    deviceOutputNode = deviceOutputNodeResult.DeviceOutputNode;

                    var microphone = await DeviceInformation.CreateFromIdAsync(
          MediaDevice.GetDefaultAudioCaptureId(AudioDeviceRole.Default));

                    var inProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateWav(AudioEncodingQuality.High);

                    var deviceInputNodeResult = await graph.CreateDeviceInputNodeAsync(MediaCategory.Speech, inProfile.Audio, microphone);

                    if (deviceInputNodeResult.Status == AudioDeviceNodeCreationStatus.Success)
                    {
                        deviceInputNode = deviceInputNodeResult.DeviceInputNode;

                        FileSavePicker saveFilePicker = new FileSavePicker();
                        saveFilePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Windows Media Audio", new List<string>() { ".wma" });
                        saveFilePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("MPEG Audio Layer-3", new List<string>() { ".mp3" });
                        saveFilePicker.SuggestedFileName = "New Audio Track";
                        StorageFile file = await saveFilePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

                        // File can be null if cancel is hit in the file picker
                        if (file == null)
                        {
                            return;
                        }

                        MediaEncodingProfile mediaEncodingProfile;
                        switch (file.FileType.ToString().ToLowerInvariant())
                        {
                            case ".mp3":
                                mediaEncodingProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp3(AudioEncodingQuality.High);
                                break;
                            case ".wav":
                                mediaEncodingProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateWav(AudioEncodingQuality.High);
                                break;
                            default:
                                throw new ArgumentException();
                        }

                        CreateAudioFileOutputNodeResult fileOutputNodeResult = await graph.CreateFileOutputNodeAsync(file, mediaEncodingProfile);

                        if (fileOutputNodeResult.Status == AudioFileNodeCreationStatus.Success)
                        {
                            fileOutputNode = fileOutputNodeResult.FileOutputNode;
                            deviceInputNode.AddOutgoingConnection(deviceOutputNode);
                            deviceInputNode.AddOutgoingConnection(fileOutputNode);
                            graph.Start();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you check manifest\capabilities for microphone access and file access. Are you getting an access denied exception?